# When creating custom serverless template, "ServerlessError: serverless.yml not found" Error

Tags: serverless-framework

I have tried to create a custom serverless template.

It is to share the same file structure between all serverless projects I have done.

```
$ serverless create --template-url https://git-repository-url --path myService
```

The below is the git repository structure for `serverless` template.

[image]

However, when I run the command above, it returns the error.

```
Serverless: Downloading and installing "xxxxxxxxxxx"...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  serverless.yml not found in /......../myService

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           10.6.0
     Serverless Version:     1.32.0
```

What have I been wrong?

If I clone the repository, I can see a `severless.yml` file on root dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used git source path URL not just git repository URL.

```
# For github
https://github.com/user/repository-name/tree/branch-name/dir-path

# For bitbucket
https://bitbucket.com/user/repository-name/src/branch-name/dir-path
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the create function works as you expect it to i.e. it wont pull in a repo from a URL.

From the [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/create/):

> **Creating a new service using a local template**
>
> `serverless create --template-path path/to/my/template/folder --path path/to/my/service --name my-new-service`

First clone your repo onto your local machine, then run the `create` command with your local path